# Client validation in Razor views not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I am trying to do the validation rules in the client and I'm not getting, always goes to the post.

Always calls the post

_Layout.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>        

<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Form:

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.UsuarioCadastro

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    <div class="row">
        @Html.TituloPagina("Informe seus dados para cadastro")    
        <div class="col-md-6">  
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nome)    
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { style = "width:250px;" })

    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Cadastrando, por favor aguarde...';this.form.submit();"/>
        </div>
    </div>    
}
```

Web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />    
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
```

Comment: check the browser console to see if the paths are well defined

Comment: no js script was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path won't mean anything to a web browser:

```
<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `~` notation is a server-side concept, referring to the application root directory.  The browser won't know what to make of that.  So I'm guessing none of the JavaScript files referenced with this notation are being loaded.

You could use the workaround that you already have in place for another `script` tag:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or you could reference the files explicitly (though this would require a change for non-root deployments, so in general cases this isn't recommended):

```
<script src="/Content/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you're using any recent version of ASP.NET MVC then I recommend constructing a [script bundle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), as that would handle the generation of the `script` tags (and even minification) for you.

Comment: @mtsys: Is MVC correcting the paths for you then?  Maybe that was a silently introduced feature in a version of MVC which was quickly replaced by bundles...  Can you examine the client-side `script` tags to see what they look like, compared with ones that "work"?

Comment: I adjusted the paths and it worked. One thing I found strange was, when I have custom attributes, it does only on the client and server. example: `public class Obrigatorio : RequiredAttribute
{ public Obrigatorio() { ErrorMessage = "* Obrigatório";  }}`